# How to register Assembly .net 4.0 in windows 7 GAC?

Tags: assemblies, gac, gacutil

Hi i'm using vs2010 to create a .net 4.0 assembly that i pretend to register on the GAC.

i can't find the gacutil and don't know ho to register an assembly on the 4.0 GAC

can someone  help?

**SOLUTION FOUND:**
Register  using GacUtil located in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either copy your assembly to your:
   %windir%\assembly 
folder, or use the Global Assembly Cache Utility found in the Microsoft SDK or Visual Studio SDK.

Comment: After a long history on googling and your help, i've realized that i've lots of possible places to get the valid GACUTIL to do the job!!! in this case it is in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools

Comment: Copying will not work and the path shown here is incorrect for .Net 4.0 assemblies