# Could not load file or assembly 'NodaTime, Version=1.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4226afe0d9b296d1' or one of its dependencies."

Tags: c#, nodatime

Currently I am creating Grasshopper 3D plugins. I was originally using the C# `DateTime` library for my time zone needs, but found `NodaTime` for how extensible and convenient it is. Fell in love immediately.

While creating [Grasshopper 3D components](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/categories/vb-c-and-python-coding/listForCategory), I referenced my assemblies via:

[image]

Grasshopper 3D components that are written in C# in Visual Studio compile as class libraries (so there's no console output). So for my preliminary development, I tested NodaTime via a console app. Same configuration, where I used the same method, same assembly, same reference adding -- the console application works just fine. But once I used that method in my Grasshopper component, I get this error:

[image]

The things I have personally tried:

1. Re-opened my Visual Studio and project.
2. Removing the references and `using` statements, and adding it again.
3. Copying [all three] portable .DLLs to my `/bin/` directory
4. Copying [all three] portable .DLLs to my`/Libaries/` directory. The `/Libraries/` directory are where the Grasshopper 3D component DLLs reside (loaded into Grasshopper for use).
5. Copy [all of the assemblies] of the NodaTime folder into my `/Libraries/` directory.
6. Setting CopyLocal of `NodaTime` to true. And to false.
7. Deleting .PDBs
8. Suggested by another user, maintained my dependencies via NuGet.

I have indeed read most if not *all* of the `could not load file or assembly` Stack Overflow threads, *and* [have](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/loading-external-dll-references-c) [checked](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/how-to-address-classes?commentId=2985220:Comment:44763) [solutions](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/best-practices-with-external-dlls-and-custom-components) in the [Grasshopper](http://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-external-dll) forums.

What could be the issue?

Comment: you have the dll from this url http://nodatime.org/downloads/ and the 1.2 release from the zipped file portable folder? may I ask why did you took the portable version and not the regular version?

Comment: I have also tried the non-portable version as well :/ I did however have the perception that the "portable" version is precisely for this reason -- is that wrong?

Comment: Ok, and the nuget package? is that an option? because it seems like you did not add a reference in visual studio, or did you?

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure how to use the nuget package version. Is it possible to use this with Visual Studio Express?

Comment: Do you have vs express 2010? or 2012? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4566908/how-can-i-use-nuget-with-visual-c-sharp-express

Comment: Oh nevermind it appears I can use nuget. From my understanding nuget is for this purpose -- consuming assemblies? Is that right? If so, how do I use it to bundle the NodaTime with my DLL? EDIT: OK. I have downloaded and installed NodaTime via nuget: http://puu.sh/7A7NY/78c70daca2.png

Comment: Does it have strong name (nodatime.dll), if so, can you try installing it into GAC ?

Comment: Yeah it has a strong name "NodaTime.DLL". According to this article, it seems there's multiple GACs depending on your .NET version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927219/how-to-register-assembly-net-4-0-in-windows-7-gac What's the "correct" path to do so? Since NodaTime is open sourced, I was heavily just considering copying the DateTime class in NodaTime to avoid the dependency issue.. EDIT: Copying it to my GAC seems like it worked!

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar -- this may sound unreasonable, but is it possible to, on compile, have the DLLs/dependencies be consumed, so users don't need to drag and drop things into GACs manually?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything with the GAC. I would certainly have *hoped* that just putting them into the Libraries directory would be enough. Can you test this with a different class library - just a dummy one with a single type and a single method?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - I'm not familiar with Grasshopper and how it load dependencies, but GAC is a place which every single .net app checks when resolving assembly dependencies + assemblies in GAC are trusted, so it might be worth a shot to install NodaTime into GAC.

Comment: Thanks guys -- since I can finally use NodaTime within my GH scripts, I'm going to fix some of the things I broke while trying to make it work, but I'll be back with answers and findings.

Comment: @JonSkeet It appears simply dragging the `.DLL`s inside the `Portable` folder to my `/Libraries/` folder does that trick. Is NodaTime open-source? Would it be illegal/unethical to take the method I use from NodaTime and put it in my code so when I distribute this application the user doesn't need to drag `NodaTime.DLL` to their `Libraries` folder?

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: Yes, Noda Time is very much open source - see http://nodatime.org. It's under the Apache 2.0 licence: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html. I *think* you'd be okay with your proposed scheme, but I haven't checked the details of the licence. I'd expect it to basically be as if you bundled the whole DLL.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am phrasing this right, but is it possible to "consume" the DLL on compile by adding it as an existing file, kinda like this? http://puu.sh/7Byyx/d3c341f7f5.png The purpose is so users don't need to download/copy NodaTime into their computers; the process to using my app will just be seamless. Of course, I will credit the creators of this great library.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage - You can consider using [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to embed NodaTime in your own assembly.